# how can i resize the captcha image + MvcCaptchaExtensionMVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, captcha

I am using MVCcaptcha in my MVC3 site, now i want to resize the default captcha image size to customized size

there is one good post about use of MVCcaptchaExtention [here](http://www.smartsoftwarebits.com/mvccaptcha/91-mvccaptcha-getting-started-howto)

but it didn't specify how to resize image

how can i resize the captcha image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSB.Web.Mvc.MvcCaptcha.Properties.Settings set

```
<setting name="MvcCaptchaWidth" serializeAs="String">
    <value>130</value>
</setting>
<setting name="MvcCaptchaHeight" serializeAs="String">
    <value>40</value>
</setting>
```